# Sailsjs market adoption, is any enterprise using it currently?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I've been working on enterprise solution using nodejs and I've come across sailsjs. I studied it and implemented a PoC on it and I am overall pretty impressed by boilerplate and other ready to use features. Still the organisation in which I work is bit skeptical about making a production app using sailsjs. So my query is: Is there any example of adoption of sailsjs as part of their enterprise solution by any of well known tech/finance companies?

Comment: You could ask the folks over at [Balderdash](http://balderdash.co/), they may be able to name some.